# How to align strings properly when they are vertical?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have a task to make a function in Python, which arranges a couple of arithmetic problems vertically, so my desired output is something like this:

```
  32         1      9999      523
+  8    - 3801    + 9999    -  49
----    ------    ------    -----
  40     -3800     19998      474
```

To produce an output like that, I wrote a "for" loop which goes through the argument (argument of this function is a list: `["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49", "555 + 555"]`), assigns them to variables and then it should print them out like in the desired output. To print it out, I wrote this:

```
    sol = \
(   f'  {first}'
    f'\n{oper}'
    f' {second}'
    f'\n{dash}'
    f'\n  {sum}')
    lst.append(sol)
```

`{first}` is the first number from the argument, `{oper}` is the operator, `{second}` is the second number, `{dash}` is the adjustable dashes, `{sum}` is the solution of the arithmetic problem. The last line appends the vertical arithmetic solutions to a list, from which I try to print them horizontally.

```
print(f'{lst[0]}    {lst[1]}    {lst[2]}    {lst[3]}')
```

But then, the output I get is this:

```
  32
+ 698
-----
  730      3801
- 2
------
  3799      45
+ 43
----
  88      123
+ 49
-----
  172
```

How to make the strings with solutions even and aligned properly?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the input data in the format you are using.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I added some more info about the problem.

Comment: There is more logic to be implemented for this task. You must evaluate width of the field from the longer of the first and second arguments plus space and operand. Then you have to right align the arguments in the given width and put the operator in place. That width is equal to the number of dashes. It's not that straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified version with no list comprehensions

```
problems = ["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49", "555 + 555"]

width = 5
space = "    "

lst = []
for problem in problems:
    lst.append(problem.split(' '))

for problem in lst:
    print(problem[0].rjust(width), end=space)
print()

for problem in lst:
    print(f"{problem[1]}{problem[2].rjust(width-1)}", end=space)
print()

for problem in lst:
    print("-" * width, end=space)
print()

for problem in problems:
    print(str(eval(problem)).rjust(width), end=space)
print()
```

The only part that might need explaining is the first for loop that creates this list:

```
[['32', '+', '698'], ['3801', '-', '2'], ['45', '+', '43'], ['123', '+', '49'], ['555', '+', '555']]
```

It has broken up each problem into a list [operand1, operator, operand2].

---

Here's the first (possible overly complex) version.

Do some pre-processing and make a list for each line then print each line.

```
problems = ["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49", "555 + 555"]

width = 5

lst = list(zip(*[p.split(' ') for p in problems]))
lines = [[s.rjust(width) for s in lst[0]],
        [f"{op}{val.rjust(width-1)}" for op,val in zip(lst[1], lst[2])],
        ['-' * (width)] * len(lst[0]),
        [str(eval(p)).rjust(width) for p in problems]]

for l in lines: print('   '.join(l))
```

Output:

```
   32    3801      45     123     555
+ 698   -   2   +  43   +  49   + 555
-----   -----   -----   -----   -----
  730    3799      88     172    1110
```

Explanation:

`lst = list(zip(*[p.split(' ') for p in problems]))`

- Splits each problem into a list. Ex: `"32 + 698"` becomes `["32", "+", "698"]`
- Then it zips each part (operand 1, operator, operand 2) into their own lists. Ex: `[('32', '3801', '45', '123', '555'), ('+', '-', '+', '+', '+'), ('698', '2', '43', '49', '555')]`

`[s.rjust(width) for s in lst[0]]`

- Creates line one with each value set to a fixed width
- Ex: `["   32", " 3801", "   45", "  123", "  555"]`

`[f"{op}{val.rjust(width-1)}" for op,val in zip(lst[1], lst[2])]`

- Line 2. Joins the operators and the 2nd operands
- Ex: `["+ 698", "-   2", "+  43", "+  49", "+ 555"]`

`['-' * (width)] * len(lst[0]),`

- Creates the 3rd line of dashes

`[str(eval(p)).rjust(width) for p in problems]`

- Last line with all the sums at the correct width

Comment: Fascinating! Works like a charm, but unfortunately, I lack knowledge to understand your code properly. That task was the assignment to do after my first programming course that I took. I guess now I have to get to know generators and list comprehension a bit better! By the way, what does asterisk do here?

Comment: The `*` operator unpacks the list. So `f(*[1,2,3])` becomes `f(1,2,3)`.

Comment: @Alexander_M I have updated with a version that does not use `zip` or list comprehensions.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer and making it more understandable for me and other beginner programmers who might stumble across a similar problem!